# Got this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a react project using Redux. I'm getting this weird error, I'm not able to resolve.

The error I see in my browser window:

```
Contacts.render
C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/contactmanager_redux/src/components/contacts/Contacts.js:18
 

     15 | const { contacts } = this.props;
      16 | return (
      17 |   <React.Fragment>
    > 18 |     <h1 className="display-4 mb-2">
         | ^  19 |       <span className="text-success">Contact</span> List
      20 |     </h1>
      21 |     {contacts.map(contact => (

View compiled

▶ 22 stack frames were collapsed.

Function.mapToProps
C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/contactmanager_redux/src/actions/contactActions.js:7
   

    4 | 
       5 | export const getContacts = () => async dispatch => {
       6 |   const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    >  7 |   dispatch({
       8 |     type: GET_CONTACTS,
       9 |     paylaod: res.data
      10 |   });

View compiled
```

This error came out when I tried to fetch the data using axios and tried to add the payload in the reducer file. I created separate action file and then brought the code to reducer using dispatch function.

Here is my Contacts.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Contact from './Contact';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// import {GET_CONTACTS} from '../../actions/types';
import {getContacts} from '../../actions/contactActions';

class Contacts extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getContacts;
  }
  
  render() {
    const { contacts } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1 className="display-4 mb-2">
          <span className="text-success">Contact</span> List
        </h1>
        {contacts.map(contact => (
          <Contact key={contact.id} contact={contact} />
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

Contacts.propTypes = {
  contacts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  getContacts: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  contacts: state.contact.contacts
});

/*const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => (
  {
    getContacts: () => (dispatch({type: GET_CONTACTS}))
  }
)*/

export default connect(mapStateToProps, getContacts)(Contacts);
```

**my ContactActions.js code:**

```
import {GET_CONTACTS, DELETE_CONTACT, ADD_CONTACT} from './types';
import axios from 'axios';


export const getContacts = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  dispatch({
    type: GET_CONTACTS,
    paylaod: res.data
  });
}

export const deleteContact = (id) => {
  return {
    type: DELETE_CONTACT,
    payload: id
  }
}

export const addContact = (contact) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_CONTACT,
    payload: contact
  }
}
```

**ContactReducer.js code:**

```
    import {GET_CONTACTS, DELETE_CONTACT, ADD_CONTACT} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  contacts: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_CONTACTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        contacts: action.payload
      };

    case DELETE_CONTACT:
      return {
        ...state,
        contacts: state.contacts.filter(contact => contact.id !== action.payload)
      }

    case ADD_CONTACT:
      return {
        ...state,
        contacts: [action.payload, ...state.contacts]
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: `contacts` is probably undefined, so `contacts.map` blows up. Related: You're not invoking `getContacts` in componentDidMount.

Comment: @rayhatfield I have invoked getContacts using this.props.getContacts

Comment: Without the parens you're not invoking it.

Comment: in your question, codes in the `ContactReducer.js` and `ContactActions.js` are the same.

Comment: @rayhatfield I'm sorry I don't understand. How to do that. Please give some more hints.

Comment: @SaeedShamloo My mistake, I have edited this. Please review.

Comment: If `this.props.getContacts` is a function, you invoke it with parens/args, like `this.props.getContacts()`. If you don't know this kind of fundamental javascript, building a React/Redux app is going to be difficult.

Comment: @rayhatfield Yes I did this, But it gave me even more errors. That's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Initally Contacts will not have data .Do conditional render like this so only the render will happen when data is available in contacts .

```
{contacts && contacts.map(contact => (
          <Contact key={contact.id} contact={contact} />
        ))}
```

Comment: this method works to get no error, But I'm still not getting the data

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of problems in your `Contacts` component:

1- Since you have commented `mapDispatchToProps`, actually you haven't send `getContacts` function to your `Contacts` component as a prop.

2- You haven't call `getContacts` in the `componentDidMount`. you just has wirtten `this.props.getContacts;` while `getContacts` must be an function and you have to call it, in order to fetch data.

I edited your `MyContact.js` file a bit, please try on this:

**MyContact.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Contact from './Contact';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// import {GET_CONTACTS} from '../../actions/types';
import {getContacts as fetchContacts} from '../../actions/contactActions';

class Contacts extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getContacts();
  }

  render() {
    const { contacts = [] } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1 className="display-4 mb-2">
          <span className="text-success">Contact</span> List
        </h1>
        {contacts.map(contact => (
          <Contact key={contact.id} contact={contact} />
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

Contacts.propTypes = {
  contacts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  getContacts: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  contacts: state.contact.contacts
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => (
  {
    getContacts: () => (dispatch(fetchContacts())
  }
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Contacts);
```

Comment: I'm using separate actions and reducers files to work with dispatch function. that's why I commented this in Contacts.js regarding this.props.getContacts() I used this too but I don't know why it gives error. when I don't use parenthesis error doesn't show up.

Comment: What is the error? without `mapDispatchToProps` the `getContacts` prop will be undefined and calling it cause to error `undefined is not a function`. is Your error message  the same?

Comment: Please have a look in the contactActions.js, there I have defined the getContacts() function and imported it in Contacts.js. 
Now I have resolved the error, But still I'm not getting the data I want to get from the API

Comment: Yes, you defined `getContacts` in the `contactActions.js` file, but since you need to access to the dispatch so you should use it as a middleware,  if you call `getContacts` directly, you don't have access to dispatch.

Comment: I used the connect() here to connect the Component to the redux store. There in my store.js I have used applyMiddleware() to use middlewares.
Actually I have resolved the issue. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
{contacts?.map(contact => (
      <Contact key={contact.id} contact={contact} />
    ))}
```